# Remove Object From SuperView but Memory still allocated? (ARC)

Tags: objective-c, macos, automatic-ref-counting

I'm having some issues with my application's memory management.  I allocate an NSView class and put it on one of my Windows.  After some time, I remove the object from the superview and then put another object in it's place.  The problem that I'm having is that the memory isn't freed when I remove it.  It continues to hold as much memory as it previously held, and if I add more of that class, it continues to pile onto the memory.  My question is, will removing that object get rid of all objects that the class held, or are some pointers being held onto, even after the object is removed?  I can post code if necessary.

Thanks!

Edit:
Here's the code that I use to allocate it

```
MyClass *theClass1 = [[MyClass alloc] initWithFrame:frameRect];
[self.window.contentView addSubview:theClass1];
```

Here's the code that I use to deallocate it

```
[[self.window.contentView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

I create it on a timer, updated every minute.  I do not reference it anywhere else.

Comment: Can you share the code where you declare, create, add and remove the subview? Do you reference it somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory for each object should be treated separately for each instance of a class. Removing one instance should not affect the allocation of other instances (unless you had some custom code looking for other instances of the class).

As for the NSView removal, `removeFromSuperview` does release the receiver (the view being removed), which is why the Apple docs on `NSView` say to `retain` it if it is still needed later.

Posting the code where it is declared, instantiated, added, then removed would be helpful for a more specific answer.

Comment: What about objects that belong to that instance of a class?  If I get rid of the view, will objects that were on that view still reside in memory?

Comment: Good question. By definition, when an object is released, so are its properties, unless you've retained them elsewhere.